# Cannot pass data to Detail View Controller Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am developing a Simple iOS 10 using Xcode 8 . I have just started learning Swift 3. I have done pretty much everything just stuck on something that I am not able to figure out. I hope seniors will clear my concept and help me out.

I have 2 problems:

1. I want to show an image also in the `tableView` cell along with the text that is being parsed from firebase.
2. I want to display data on a detail view controller (`DetailsVC`) a image, a heading and description when user touches any cell.
   I have created a class and the data is parsed from Firebase, I have managed to get the data shown on tableview cell (`HomeVC`), but I am unable to send the data when a cell is touched to the detail view controller (`DetailsVC`). I want to show a heading (title) of an image and description in the detail view controller.

Firebase:

[image: Firebase]

DetailsVC:

[image: DetailsVC]

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase


class HomeVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    var posts = [Model]()


    var ref:FIRDatabaseReference?
    var handle:FIRDatabaseHandle?

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "homecell" , for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellHomeVC

        let post: Model

        post = posts[indexPath.row]

        cell.headingLabel.text = post.heading

        return cell
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {

        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts")
        ref?.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

                for posts in snapshot.children.allObjects as![FIRDataSnapshot]{
                    let postsObject = posts.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let heading = postsObject?["heading"]
                    let image = postsObject?["image"]
                    let description = postsObject?["description"]
                    let post = Model(heading: (heading as! String?)!, image: (image as! String?)!, description: (description as! String?)!)

                    self.posts.append(post)
                }

                self.myTableView.reloadData()
            }
        })

    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let details = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsVC") as! DetailsVC

        details.testing = posts[indexPath.row] as! String


        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(details, animated: true)

    }

    }
```

**Model**

```
> import Foundation
import UIKit


class Model {

    var heading:String?

    var image:UIImage?



    var description:String?


    init(heading : String,image : String,description : String) {
        self.heading = heading
        //self.image = image
        self.description = description
    }

}
```

Comment: you can use **Segue** to get the expected result

Comment: Can you explain how ? as i did use segue before using didselectrowat but couldnt pass data as i also need to pass image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass string instead of model because your array `posts` contained **Model class**.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let details = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsVC") as! DetailsVC
        let post: Model
         post = posts[indexPath.row]

        details.testing = post.heading as! String // if your want to pass model class object then create object in DetailsVC and pass here.
        details.objPosts = post   // this for sample if you want to pass model object    

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(details, animated: true)

    }

}
```

**In DetailController**

```
var objPosts : Model = nil // declare this property
```

// in viewDidLoad

```
let url = URL(string: objPosts.image)
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)

if let imageData = data {
    let image = UIImage(data: data) // assign this image to your imageview
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot .. That worked pretty well.. But how can i pass an image to show in detailsVC ? As the post contains an image url that is stored in the firebase storage, i need to display that image in the uiimage view in detailsVC . Can you please help me with that too.. my application will be completed

Comment: welcome .... you can pass this post object to the verifyController . as i suggested and render that url to image .

Comment: Did not get that to work.. as i add it in the detailsVC i get http://prntscr.com/fe6mcy also my class doesnt have image in the init() .. as it gives me error when i try to add it http://prntscr.com/fe6mqe

Comment: you need write code inside of viewDidLoad in detaiviewcontroller and replace with var objPosts : Model == nil

Comment: and https://prnt.sc/fe6mqe this error due to you have assigned string to UIImage .

Comment: The code changed by xcode .. as the model var changed to optional and also the below code..But how will i pass the image string ? that is coming from Firebase in my class Model ?when i click a tableviewcell that app crashes now . http://prntscr.com/fe6wcf

Comment: you need to check    let image = postsObject?["image"] ? is this nil or not .

Comment: you need to search in google that how to get image from url so because as per your question i given my answer .

Comment: oh yes  sorry.. and thanks alot .. i got consfused.. now i just need to convert the string to uiimage :)

Comment: if testing string are passed successfully to detail viewcontroller then you can use this way to pass image string to detailVC.

Comment: I am using swift 4 and is still working perfectly. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass heading string means please try below code.

```
let post: Model
post = posts[indexPath.row]
let heading = post.heading  
details.testing = heading
```

Thanks.